# asp .net Get hexadecimal color to calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get a hex color using c# in ASp .net with the following code:

```
 System.Windows.Media.Color color = (Color)System.Windows.Media
                                                 .ColorConverter            
                                                 .ConvertFromString("##009999");
 Calendar1.BackColor = color;
```

and I get the following error:

> Error    6   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Color'
>
> to 'System.Drawing.Color.

Any Help?

Comment: IF you need a System.Drawing.Color is there any reason you are going via a System.Windows.Media.Color? It looks like you have a pretty standard hex color string that could be converted to a Color directly I'd have thought... (via code like `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC66")`;)

Comment: Media.Color to Drawing-Color: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615779/converting-system-windows-media-color-to-system-drawing-color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact on rereading the question again I think this is the answer:

```
System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#009999")
```

Note that you only want one `#` in the input string (so you may need to prune if your input has two).

This will give you a `System.Drawing.Color` which looks like it is what you want without worrying about `System.Windows.Media.Color`